How can we prove that $\langle f, g\rangle = \sum_{k \in \Gamma}\langle f, e_k \rangle\langle e_k, g \rangle$?
Suppose that $\{e_k\}_{k \in \Gamma}$ is an orthonormal basis of a Hilbert space $V$ and $f,g \in V$.
We know that $f = \sum_{k \in \Gamma} \langle f, e_k \rangle e_k$, where the summation is an unordered sum.
How can we prove that $\langle f, g\rangle = \sum_{k \in \Gamma}\langle f, e_k \rangle\langle e_k, g \rangle$?
My try:
Given $\epsilon>0$, let's us chose the superset of $\Omega_1, \Omega_2$ (both finite subsets of $\Gamma$, by def. of unordered sum), calling it $\Omega$, such that we have for all $\Omega'_1 \supset \Omega_1$ and $\Omega'_2 \supset \Omega_2$:
$$|\langle\sum_{k \in \Gamma} \langle f, e_k \rangle e_{k}, g \rangle - \langle\sum_{k \in \Omega'_1} \langle f, e_k \rangle e_k, g \rangle|
< \epsilon /2 $$
and $$|\sum_{k \in \Omega'_2}\langle f, e_k \rangle \langle e_k, g \rangle-\sum_{k \in \Gamma}\langle f, e_k \rangle\langle e_k, g \rangle|< \epsilon /2$$
Then for all $\Omega' \supset \Omega$,
\begin{align*}
|\langle f, g\rangle - \sum_{k \in \Gamma}\langle f, e_k \rangle\langle e_k, g \rangle| &\leq |\langle\sum_{k \in \Gamma} \langle f, e_k \rangle e_k, g \rangle - \langle\sum_{k \in \Omega'} \langle f, e_k \rangle e_k, g \rangle| \\
& + |\langle\sum_{k \in \Omega'} \langle f, e_k \rangle e_k, g \rangle-\sum_{k \in \Gamma}\langle f, e_k \rangle\langle e_k, g \rangle| \\
&< \epsilon
\end{align*}
The problem is that the book suggests using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, and I don't see the need to use it in this setting... Have I done something wrong?

Are you assuming that $\Gamma$ is countable? If not, how is the summation defined?

@copper.hat For any fixed $f$ the cardinality of $e_k$ for which $\langle f,e_k\langle \neq 0$ is countable.

@copper.hat Good question! Even though the book is silent about that, after researching for your question,  it seems that in a normed space, for the summation to be convergent, gamma must be countable. https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m201b_old/sums.pdf

It was just a clarifying question, some older books assume separability for Hilbert spaces (Kolmogorov & Fomin, for example). This can trip you up if you are not aware of the convention.

Cauchy Schwartz/Bessel's inequality can be used to show that $\langle f,g \rangle = \sum_k \bar{\hat{f}_k}\langle e_k,g \rangle = \sum_k \bar{\hat{f}_k} \hat{g}_k$.

What is typically meant by the convergence of such a series is as follows. Let $X$ be a normed space and let $\mathcal{F}$ denote the set consisting of finite subsets of a set $\Gamma$. The series $(\sum_{\alpha\in F} x_{\alpha} )_{F\in\mathcal{F}}$ of terms indexed by $\Gamma$ converges to $x$ in $X$ if for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there is some $F_{0}\in \mathcal{F}$ such that whenever $F\in\mathcal{F}$ and $F_{0} \subseteq F$, $\| \sum_{\alpha \in F}x_{\alpha} - x \| < \varepsilon$. Another way to see this is that $(\mathcal{F}, \subseteq )$ forms a directed set and the convergence defined above is equivalent to the net $(\sum_{\alpha\in F} x_{\alpha} )_{F\in\mathcal{F}}$ converging to $x$ in $X$. All of this is discussed on pages 5-6 of the notes you sent through in the comments.
Note that in your proposed solution, $\sum_{k\in\Gamma}\langle f, e_{k}\rangle$ is a scalar if it exists while $g$ is in the Hilbert space $V$, so it does not make sense to talk about $\langle \sum_{k\in\Gamma}\langle f, e_{k}\rangle, g\rangle$.
Let's instead start off with an observation. If $F$ is a finite subset of $\Gamma$, by the linearity of the first entry of the inner product,
$$\sum_{k\in F}\langle f, e_{k}\rangle \langle e_{k}, g\rangle = \left\langle \sum_{k\in F} \langle f, e_{k}\rangle e_{k}, g\right\rangle .$$
As a result, for each finite subset $F$ of $\Gamma $,
$$
\sum_{k\in F}\langle f, e_{k}\rangle \langle e_{k}, g\rangle - \langle f, g\rangle = \left\langle \sum_{k\in F} \langle f, e_{k}\rangle e_{k}, g\right\rangle - \langle f,g\rangle = \left\langle \sum_{k\in F} \langle f, e_{k}\rangle e_{k} - f, g\right\rangle .
$$
Note that the left-most expression is the one that is supposed to be estimated as the set $F$ becomes larger under the notion of set inclusion and that the right-most expression can be estimated by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ denote the finite subsets of $\Gamma$. As the series $(\sum_{k\in F}\langle f, e_{k}\rangle e_{k})_{F\in\mathcal{F}}$ converges to $f$ in $V$, there is a finite subset $F_{0}$ of $\Gamma$ such that if $F$ is a finite subset of $\Gamma$ containing $F_{0}$, $\|\sum_{k\in F}\langle f, e_{k}\rangle e_{k} - f\| < \varepsilon$. It follows that if $F$ is a finite subset of $\Gamma$ containing $F_{0}$, by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
\begin{align*}
\left|\sum_{k\in F}\langle f, e_{k}\rangle \langle e_{k}, g\rangle - \langle f, g\rangle \right| &= \left| \left\langle \sum_{k\in F} \langle f, e_{k}\rangle e_{k} - f, g\right\rangle \right| \\
&\leq \left\|\sum_{k\in F}\langle f, e_{k}\rangle e_{k} - f \right\| \|g\| \\
&\leq \varepsilon \|g\|.
\end{align*}
By the definition of the convergence of unordered sums, it follows that $(\sum_{k\in\Gamma}\langle f, e_{k}\rangle \langle e_{k}, g\rangle )_{F\in\mathcal{F}}$ converges to $\langle f, g\rangle$.

Thanks for pointing out some typos. I think I've corrected them all... Is my try correct, now?
Also thanks for the part related to the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

No problem. It's a bit unclear what you are using to obtain $\Omega_{1}$ and $\Omega_{2}$ at the start of the proof. I think you need to use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to justify the first equation. For the second equation, you are already assuming the series converges, but you don't have that assumption. You need to first show that it converges in order to use the summation definition. I think there is also a small typo in the first equation.

Thanks for the patience, Dean ;)

For $f\in V$ let $$A_{f,n} =\{ k\in \Gamma\,:\, |\langle f,e_k\rangle |\ge n^{-1} \}$$ The set $A_{f,n}$ is finite as by the Bessel inequality we have
$$\|f\|^2\ge \sum_{k\in A_{f,n}}|\langle f,e_k\rangle |^2\ge \sum_{k\in A_{f,n}}n^{-2}$$ We have $$A_f:=\{k\in \Gamma\,:\, \langle f,e_k\rangle\neq 0\}=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_{f,n}$$ Therefore $A_f$ is countable. For $ f,g\in V$ the set $A_f\cup A_g$ is  countable as well. Hence $$A_f\cup A_g\subset \{k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_n,\ldots\}$$ and $f,g\in V_0,$ where $V_0$ is the closed linear span of the orthonormal set $\{e_{k_j}\}_{j=1}^\infty.$ For $h\in V_0$ we have $$h=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \langle h,e_{k_j}\rangle e_{k_j}$$ Let $$h_n=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \langle h,e_{k_j}\rangle e_{k_j}$$ Then $f_n\perp g-g_n$ and $g_n\perp f-f_n.$ Therefore we  get $$\langle f,g\rangle=\langle f_n,g_n\rangle +\langle f- f_n,g-g_n\rangle\\ =\sum_{j=1}^n  \langle f,e_{k_j}\rangle \langle e_{k_j},g\rangle +\langle f- f_n,g-g_n\rangle$$ Next $$|\langle f- f_n,g-g_n\rangle| \le \|f-f_n\|\,\|g-g_n\|\to 0$$ Thus $$  \langle f,g\rangle =\sum_{j=1}^\infty  \langle f,e_{k_j}\rangle \langle e_{k_j},g\rangle =\sum_{k\in \Gamma } \langle f,e_{k}\rangle \langle e_{k},g\rangle $$
